# "the database you have selected is not a report server database" error on SSRS configuration

Tags: reporting-services, configuration, ssrs-2012

I want to configurate SSRS report server
When I try to database step and I choose the “Choose an existing report server database” I get an this error:
I added screenshot of this situation in below.

[image: screenhot1]

When I choose the “Create a new report server database” from database step, I get an this error:
I added screenshot of this situation in below.

[image: screenhot2]

Could you please help me how we can proceed this situation?

Comment: Are you sure that is a report server database? The database names are normally called ReportServer and ReportServerTempDb

Answer (score 1):

You want to be creating a new report server database, but this time with a different name from the database you already have. Let it choose the default report server database names, not overwrite it with your own.

SSRS uses separate databases, not the ones with your data in.

Comment: Yeah the common practice is to name it ReportServer$Your_DB_Name